# Android SSL SNI connection issues

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, sni

I have an app that serves to consume and update data to a webserver and, recently, the app owner decided to switch to a secure connection due to personal information stored.

The server is already set up as SNI and I have checked it using [digicert](https://www.digicert.com/help/), the server is working fine and seems to be set up correctly, but does **not** include the path *.host.com on its alternate names (I am unsure if this is normal or not for SNI).

The iOS worked like a charm, however on Android I get this error:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

My current connection method looks like this:

```
    URL url = new URL(postURL);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    SSLContext sc;
    sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    String userpass = "bob" + ":" + "12345678";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

    conn.setReadTimeout(7000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    conn.connect();

    InputStream instream = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));

    StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        everything.append(line);
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(everything.toString());

    return jsonObject;
```

I'm not quite sure what's the issue here, but trying to connect to https://sni.velox.ch/ gives me a long answer that seems like a success.

Also, I do have the pem key for the certificate here with me, but I do not know how I add that in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you get this error when using a self-signed certificate, in which case you would have to use the certificate while making the request.

Additionally, you might be getting this error because of not including the path ***.host.com**.

You could try the below code to pass your certificate while building the `HttpsURLConnection`. Please don't forget to copy the **ca.pem** file to assets folder.

```
private HttpsURLConnection buildSslServerConnection() {
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(context.getAssets().open("ca.pem"));
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" + Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(7000);
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while checking server connectivity: ", e);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while checking server connectivity: ", e);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while checking server connectivity: ", e);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while checking server connectivity: ", e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while checking server connectivity: ", e);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while checking server connectivity: ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while checking server connectivity: ", e);
    }
    return urlConnection;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but sadly it did not work. Just for clarification sake, the ca.pem should go in the assets folder located in the same directory as java and res folders, correct? I also tried moving it to raw (and make the necessary adjustments) to no avail.

Comment: If you are using maven, it should be inside `src/main/assets/ca.pem`. Else if you are using standard Android project structure, the assets folder would be located in the same directory as `res`, `src`, `libs`, `AndroidManifest.xml`...

Comment: Yes, it was in the correct place `src/main/assets/ca.pem`, if I put it on any other location it gives me an error mentioning it was impossible to find the certificate. But I'm still getting the `Trust anchor for certification path not found`.

Comment: It's weird that the code doesn't work for you. Just to clarify, you do have the right pem file, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was told by the server administrator. It's not an actual copy of the certificate, but it is a pem file generated with its unique key/fingerprint (not sure what it is called in this context), which is supposed to be enough, isn't it?

Comment: Just to give closure to this whole ordeal, yes, as it turns out it was a certificate issue server-side, but it was ANOTHER certificate altogether that I never tried to use or access which caused Android to refuse to establish a connection.

Comment: Had almost forgotten about this. Thank you for the closure :)